# Android continuous tcp polling

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, project

I am working on a project in which I can see webcam images from the people who is in front of the door on my Android app.

But I am getting a bit confused. I've managed to setup a connection with a service on my phone to a server which handles the image sending.

But i only want to get images from the server when someone presses the doorbell, so I need to send a notification or something to my app so I know there is one in front of the door, and I want to decide if I want to answer his call or not.

Now this is why I am confused: if I open the tcp socket in the android service, how can I know that my server sends a 'call' message, because the tcp socket is openend when the service is created. Do I need to keep polling every second? Then there is still a little chance that I will miss the call message?

Or do I have to run the application as server and the doorbell as client, so the client request a connection?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how do you detect a doorbell event? Is the server placedin the same location as the door and camera are? Who detects the doorbell, the server or the android client?

Comment: The server is a linux based computer running a Qt program wich is the server application.  When the doorbell is pressed, the Qt program will recognize this and will send to the client (android app) that the doorbell is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at cloud to device messaging, c2dm , a lot more power efficient too. Built into android.
https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: So you recommend to use the C2DM and send a message from the server to the cloud, the cloud to my android. So can i send messages back from my android to the cloud or do i need to open an tcp socket for reading the images? I am using Qt(c++) to write my server side

Comment: @Gunther The server can have an open socket awaiting for clients, and when the doorbell rings, it sends a C2DM message so that the client android app can open the socket and start receiving image feed.

Comment: hmm that seems very usefull, I will try it that way, thanx!

Comment: I looked for the C2DM for a time now, but I can't seem to get it working.. I want to program the server in Qt/c++ but there is no tutorial or something.. Is there maybe another way to do it?

Comment: As per the link I gave in the answer, or more specifically this section https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#server , your server only has to be able to communicate over http as a client, that is, post a message (fairly simple to do over a tcp socket if you don't want to involve a http client lib, though a lib is probably preferable)

Answer (score 0):

If the tcp socket is opened when the service is created, just send some appropriate message from the server to connected clients. If your client is connected, it will get it.  You only need to poll if the client continually connects and disconnects, eg. like many HTTP 1 web services.